# Updated JSON file is not reading during runtime

Tags: karate

Team,
I have service to register a user with certain data along with unique mail id and phone no in JSON file format as a body (for ex: registerbody.json). 
Before Post call I am generating unique mail id , phone no and updating the same json file (registerbody.json) fields which is in the same folder where feature file locates. I see the file is updated with the required data during runtime.

I used read () method and performed POST request

Surprisingly read method is not taking updated JSON file instead it is reading old data in the registerbody.json file.

Do you have any idea on this, why it is picking up old data even though file is updated with the latest information?

Please assist me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate uses the Java classpath, which is typically `target/test-classes`. So if you edit a file in `src/test/java` Karate won't see it unless it is copied. This copying is automatically done when you build / compile your code.

My suggestion is use `target/` as a temp folder and then you can read using the `file:` prefix:

```
* def payload = read('file:some.json')
```

> Before Post call I am generating unique mail id , phone no and updating the same json file (registerbody.json)

You are making a big mistake here, Karate specializes in updating JSON based on variables. I suggest you take 5 minutes and read this part of the docs VERY carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

Especially the part about embedded expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

Comment: Hi , Thanks. With the "file" keyword in the read method is working fine and updated data file picked up. Yes, I went through the 'reading-files' section earlier, somehow I didn't get this. Thanks for your support in this. You can close this request.

Comment: @KiranEdupuganti can you please share the code snipet of read file code ? I am also facing similar issue and still not resolved.